Firemonkey - Como remover ou ocultar ponteiro em forma de "bolha" no foco do componente Edit
O componente TEdit do Firemonkey quando recebe o foco da aplicação está exibindo um ponteiro de posicionamento de texto em formato de bolha, que é algo que não estava acontecendo antes.
Existe alguma forma de remover ou ocultar este ponteiro ou se trata de alguma atualização do Android?
Obrigado.
Imagem do ponteiro

Boas-vindas Valdir. Em um projeto criado do zero a "bolha" aparece?

Não testei essa possibilidade. Vou verificar e dou retorno.

Acabei de testar e sim ela aparece.
Obrigado.

Problema resolvido.
Na edição do estilo do TEdit, remover o objeto CARETPOINT.
Remoção do Objeto
